# Having trouble grokking CSS 2.1 grammar

Tags: c#, grammar, w3c, css

I am writing a hand-coded CSS 2.1 parsing engine (in C#), and I'm working directly off the W3C CSS 2.1 grammar (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html). However, there's a token that I just don't quite get:

```
url     ([!#$%&*-~]|{nonascii}|{escape})*

...

"url("{w}{url}{w}")"    {return URI;}
"url("{w}{string}{w}")" {return URI;}
```

I don't get what the URL production is supposed to do. It appears to be a string of only `!#$%&*-~`, non-ascii, or escaped unicode code points. How is that a URL? Is this production just really badly named, and what purpose is it supposed to serve?

Any help appreciated. *FYI, I've added the C# tag only to increase the audience to actual programmers who might have encountered this or have insights - I apologize if you think I shouldn't apply.*

Answer (score 2):

Dude, did you read the CONTEXT surrounding that expression?

```
baduri1         url\({w}([!#$%&*-\[\]-~]|{nonascii}|{escape})*{w}
baduri2         url\({w}{string}{w}
baduri3         url\({w}{badstring}
```

Hmmm... Bad, bad, bad. Bit of a giveaway, eh what? Generally, If something in the doco doesn't make sense to you, or appears just plain wrong, maybe it shouldn't make sense? Yes? So you read around it... to acquire the correct context.

Comment: And what of this production?

     `import
        : IMPORT_SYM S*
          [STRING|URI] S* media_list? ';' S*
     ;`

Comment: What I'm not understanding is that if that production references URI, which is only returned by those two expressions, then where does baduri come into play? It looks as if the grammar is saying that when parsing an import, a URI like `url(!#$\abcdef)` is perfectly valid. Does FLEX have some special, automatic meaning of a production prefixed by "bad" or something?

Answer (score 2):

`[!#$%&*-~]` breaks down to:

`!`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, plus the character range `*` - `~`.

This takes in most printable ASCII characters, including uppercase, lowercase, digits and a range of punctuation characters.

It's easier to list the printable ASCII characters which this regex doesn't match:

Double quote `"`,  single quote `'`, and parenthesis `(`, `)`; i.e printable ascii characters minus delimiters. This makes it possible to parse urls that do not include quotation marks. E.g. `url(http://example.com)`, instead of  `url("http://example.com")`.

Concise, but tricky!

P.S. The token name is confusing as well. A better name would have been something like: `url_string` or `url_arg`.

**EDIT Feb 2015** The latest [CSS3 Syntax Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-css-syntax-3-20140220/#typedef-url-token) names the token `url-unquoted`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get what the URL production is supposed to do. It appears to be a string of only !#$%&*-~, non-ascii, or escaped unicode code points. How is that a URL? Is this production just really badly named, and what purpose is it supposed to serve?

The first line defines `url` as a regular expression:

```
url     ([!#$%&*-~]|{nonascii}|{escape})*
```

The second line defines `URI` as a token which can be produced/returned by the lexer:

```
"url("{w}{url}{w}")"    {return URI;}
```

The second line says that if the lexer sees `url(` then `{w}` then `{url}` then `{w}` then `)` then it has found a URI.

The `{w}` expression is optional whitespace.

So according to the definition, the `{url}` is a regular expression: which defines what characters are allow inside a `URI` token, between the initial `url(` and the final `)`.